# Facebook login not responding

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am creating an app in Android Phonegap  which use Facebook SDK to register. I done all the steps for integrating FB SDK to my app but while Iam clicking the login (or register with FB button) in the app, it log in to the FB but not giving response back to the app it force-closes the app after login to FB. I can't get any solution. Here is my code :

```
function chklogin() {
                FB.login(
                         function(response) {
                         if (response.session) {
                         alert('logged in');
                         } else {
                         alert('not logged in');
                         }
                         },
                         { scope: "email" }
                         );
            }
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                              console.log('document.addEventListener');
                               try {

                                      FB.init({ appId: "****", 
                                      nativeInterface: CDV.FB, 
                                      useCachedDialogs: false });
                                      console.log('init');

                                      } catch (e) {

                                      }
                                      }, false);
```

here is my Facebook login button code :

```
<div class="log_bottom">
     <a href="#" id="registerwithfb"><input type="submit" data-role="button" data-    transition="fade" data-theme="b"  onclick="chklogin()" class="forcolouredbuttontext submit" value="REGISTER WITH FACEBOOK" /></a>
</div>
```

i saw some similar question but cant find the correct solution please help thanks

Comment: if you get any error log post here , it helps us to answer